# awk: multiline sort and delete not working as expected with RS

Tags: awk

Im struggling with a multiline file which has a `RS of \n (\012)` and a FS of `\035`.

My ultimate target is to delete duplicates based on a certain column but the file is not fixed width and some columns are optional.

Ive tried to parse the file using the following commands:

`awk -v FS='\035' -v RS= -v ORS='\n' '{print $4}' filename`

`awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n"; FS="\035"} {print NR, NF, $0}' filename`

`awk  -v RS='\012' -F'\035' '!seen[$4]++' filename`

Unfortunately what is happening is if a record spans over multiple lines, awk is not treating these lines as part of a record:

```
1 "Column4"
2 "Column4"
3
4 "Column4"
5
6 "Column4"
7
8
9
10 "Column4"
```

In the above file, the blank lines represent part of the record, so line number 4 should actually be line number 3 (Column4 does not exist in line 3 as it is a multiline record from line 2). Spanned records end in ^M$ and end of record ends only in $ when I view the file in vi editor.

I hope someone can guide me on how to read this file properly so I can ultimately delete the records based on duplicate Column4 values.

`awk  -v RS='\012' -F'\035' '!seen[$4]++' filename`

The above only works on single line records, but I would need help with deleting duplicate lines based on Column4 regardless of single or multiline but should consider the RS and FS.

Adding sample input:

```
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"ABCD"^]"121212"^]"1"^]"Some^M$
test data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"DEFG"^]"121212"^]"1"^]"Some test data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"HIJK"^]"232323"^]"1"^]"Some test ^M$
data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"LMNO"^]"232323"^]"1"^]"Some ^M$
test ^M$
data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"PQRS"^]"343434"^]"1"^]"Some test data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"121212"^]"343434"^]"1"^]"Some ^M$
Test^M$
^M$
data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"TUVW"^]"565656"^]"1"^]"Some^M$
test^M$
data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$
```

Output should only print unique Column 4 values:

```
121212
232323
343434
565656
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: How do you know  if its a genuine line break or  not ? also for removing  control M `^M` characters try `dos2unix`

Comment: @Digvijay S if I remove the Control M chars, there wont be an indication if the record is multiline or a single line record.

Comment: try `tr  '\n' '  ' | tr '\r' '\n'`  <file

Comment: There are too many commands, too much confusion, and no sample input in your question. Create a small but representative sample input file. Run `cat -Ev file` on it to display where the CRs and LFs are with `^M` and `$` characters respectively. Copy/paste that into your question as sample input and add the expected output given that input plus the command you think should produce that output and what it actually output. Given that we can definitely help you.

Comment: @DigvijayS that will corrupt the input.

Comment: Hi Ed, Ive added the sample. Sorry about that.

Comment: In your example input, I don't see a single multi-line record. They are all ending with CR. Can you confirm that the record separator is actually "GSCR" (\035\012)

Comment: the second line is a single record:
"TEST"^]"1234"^]"DEFG"^]"121212"^]"1"^]"Some test data"^]"0"^]"08.06.2020"^]$

Comment: So, can you confirm that your record separator is actually GSCR (\035\012)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are interested in is the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\035"}
     (record && $0 ~ "\035$") { split(record,a); if (!s[a[4]]++) print record; record="" }
     { record = record (record?"ORS":"") $0 }
     END { split(record,a); if (!s[a[4]]++) print record; }' file
```

Or with GNU awk for multi-character `RS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\035";RS="\035\012"}!s[$4]++' file
```

Comment: Why are you using $6? I tried this by replacing it with $4 and no output. With your command it produces incorrect results.

Comment: Sorry, should be $4

Comment: Ended up using this for:
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\035";RS="\035\012"} !s[$4]++' filename,
Thanks